# Error "different target namespace", but schema validates and namespaces match?

Tags: xml, xsd, namespaces, xsd-validation, xerces

I have an XSD and several different XML messages that are being sent from a client to a server, which is attempting to validate the messages using the schema.  I'm using Xerces for parsing.  The XSD and XML are both valid, and I ran it through a couple tools ([for example](http://www.utilities-online.info/xsdvalidation/)) to verify that the XML is validated using that schema.

However, when I run the program, it prints out:

`Parsing Error: Schema in /path/to/xsd/MySchema.xsd has a different target namespace from the one specified in the instance document .`

(That path is the correct location of the schema, so it is reading the file as expected.) I don't know much about namespaces, so I tried to simplify as much as possible. Here's the XSD file:

```
<xs:schema
        xmlns="http://www.mywebsite.com/schema/myschema"
        xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
        elementFormDefault="qualified"
        attributeFormDefault="unqualified"
        targetNamespace="http://www.mywebsite.com/schema/myschema">
    <xs:element name="My_Data">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="PartOne" type="SubType" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
                <xs:element name="PartTwo" type="xs:integer" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:complexType name="SubType">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="ElemOne" type="xs:string" />
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

And the XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no" ?>
<My_Data
    xmlns="http://www.mywebsite.com/schema/myschema"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <PartOne>
        <ElemOne>thing</ElemOne>
    </PartOne>
    <PartTwo>123</PartTwo>
</My_Data>
```

I've tried many variations on this including adding a schemaLocation attribute, but it keeps coming back to the target namespace. If I take out `ElemOne` from the above example and do not use a targetNamespace, it parses without problems.  Why would I get this error?  Is it actually an issue with namespaces (in which case, why would the online tool not catch it?), or something else?

EDIT: here is the C++ code I am using to run this:

```c
// g++ -g -Wall -pedantic -L /usr/lib -o schemasend schemasend.cc CustomParserErrorHandler.cc -lxerces-c

#include <xercesc/framework/MemBufInputSource.hpp>
#include "CustomParserErrorHandler.hh"
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  xercesc::XMLPlatformUtils::Initialize();
  std::cout << "Intialized" << std::endl;
  try {
    // Parse document
    const std::string aXML = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\" standalone=\"no\" ?><My_Data xmlns=\"http://www.mywebsite.com/schema/myschema\" xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\"><PartOne><ElemOne>thing</ElemOne></PartOne><PartTwo>123</PartTwo></My_Data>";
    static std::string aXSDFilePath("MySchema.xsd");

    CustomParserErrorHandler aErrorHandler; // just a very basic implementation of error handling

    const xercesc::MemBufInputSource aInputSource(
      (const XMLByte*)aXML.c_str(), 
      static_cast<uint>(aXML.size()), 
      "stringBuffer");

    xercesc::XercesDOMParser* aParser = new xercesc::XercesDOMParser();
    aParser->cacheGrammarFromParse(true);

    aParser->setErrorHandler(&aErrorHandler);
    aParser->setDoNamespaces(true);
    aParser->setDoSchema(true);
    aParser->setValidationSchemaFullChecking(true);
    aParser->setValidationScheme(xercesc::XercesDOMParser::Val_Always);
    aParser->setExternalNoNamespaceSchemaLocation((char*)NULL);
    aParser->setExternalNoNamespaceSchemaLocation(aXSDFilePath.c_str());

    aParser->setDoNamespaces(true);
    aParser->setDoSchema(true);
    aParser->setValidationScheme(xercesc::XercesDOMParser::Val_Always);

    aParser->parse(aInputSource);
    xercesc::DOMDocument* aDocument = aParser->getDocument();
    if (!aErrorHandler.HasErrorOccurred())
    {
      std::cout << "--- PARSE WORKED ---" << std::endl;
      // do more things
    }
    else
    {
      std::cout <<"--- PARSE ERROR ---" << std::endl
        << aErrorHandler.GetErrorString().c_str() << std::endl
        << "--- IN XML ---" << std::endl
        << aXML.c_str() << std::endl;

        /* relevant error handler code:
          void CustomParserErrorHandler::HandleError(
              const xercesc::SAXParseException &aException,
              std::stringstream                &aStream)
          {
            aStream
              << xercesc::XMLString::transcode(aException.getMessage())
              << " at line " << aException.getLineNumber()
              << ", char " << aException.getColumnNumber()
              << " in file " 
              << xercesc::XMLString::transcode(aException.getSystemId())
              << std::endl;
          }
        */
    }
  }
  catch (const xercesc::XMLException& toCatch) {
    std::cout << "ERROR" << std::endl;
    return 1;
  }

  xercesc::XMLPlatformUtils::Terminate();
  std::cout << "bye" << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was in my C++ code rather than XML/XSD files. When I commented out the line

```
aParser->setExternalNoNamespaceSchemaLocation(aXSDFilePath.c_str());
```

it no longer gave the error message. I'm not sure why this made a difference, because as far as I can tell there isn't anything *not* in a namespace, but it fixed the issue I was seeing.